# Unable to find R in ubuntu while r-base is correctly installed

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS ,  I decided to update my version of R to 4.3. After encountering several difficulties, I completely removed R (including removing all system files related to R, such as /usr/lib/R). However, even after reinstalling R, I was unable to get the program to work. All the programs that are using R like Rstudio are not working and it looks like R is not found by Ubuntu.

```
command not found: R
```

But if I try to reinstall R, it indicates that everything is properly installed.

```
~ ❯❯❯ sudo apt install -y r-base r-base-core r-recommended r-base-dev    ✘ 127 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
r-base-core is already the newest version (4.3.0-1.2204.0).
r-base-dev is already the newest version (4.3.0-1.2204.0).
r-base is already the newest version (4.3.0-1.2204.0).
r-recommended is already the newest version (4.3.0-1.2204.0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
```

I have tried multiple times to uninstall and reinstall, but I haven't found any solution.

Comment: AFAIK, apt doesn't check for the existence of the files it is supposed to install. So if you manually deleted the system files, apt looks at its database and think it is already installed. Try to use the `--reinstall` flag: `sudo apt install --reinstall r-base r-base-core ...`

Comment: This question might be better asked on askubuntu.com.